# Utilizing validate() Inside of a Modal Dialogue in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app in which I have a modal dialogue which collects some user inputs and has an action button to confirm those input values. Whenever the user confirms the inputs, I would like to perform some basic validation tests on the user inputs before using them to calculate new value. I have been attempting to use the shiny validate() function for this in order to display custom error messages to the user, but I cannot figure out how to get the validate() messages to show up in the modal dialogue for the user. Following is a minimal reproducible example. Thanks for the help!

````
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("modal", 
                   label = "Modal")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  modalFunction <- bindEvent(observe({
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "Modal",
        numericInput("n1", "Number:", value = 0),
        numericInput("n2", "Other number:", value = 0),
        footer = tagList(actionButton("confirm_modal",
                                      label = "Confirm"),
                         modalButton("Cancel"))
      )
    )
  }), input$modal)
  
  modalCalculations <- bindEvent(observe({
    validate(
      need(input$n1 != input$n2, "Warning: Ensure that the two inputs are not equal."),
      need(input$n1 + input$n2 <= 10, "Warning: Ensure that the two inputs do not sum to greater than 10.")
    )
    
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        renderText(paste0("Success! The sum is ", input$n1 + input$n2, " and the difference is ", input$n1 - input$n2, ".")),
        footer = tagList(modalButton("Return"))
      )
    )
  }), input$confirm_modal)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (`?validate`)

> validate() provides convenient mechanism for validating that an output has all the inputs necessary for successful rendering.

Hence, move `validate()` inside the `renderText` (aka the output) of your second modal to display your error messages:

```
modalCalculations <- bindEvent(observe({
  showModal(
    modalDialog(
      renderText({
        validate(
          need(
            input$n1 != input$n2,
            "Warning: Ensure that the two inputs are not equal."
          ),
          need(
            input$n1 + input$n2 <= 10,
            "Warning: Ensure that the two inputs do not sum to greater than 10."
          )
        )

        paste0(
          "Success! The sum is ", input$n1 + input$n2,
          " and the difference is ", input$n1 - input$n2, "."
        )
      }),
      footer = tagList(modalButton("Return"))
    )
  )
}), input$confirm_modal)
```

[image]